# Axios gives undefined while accessing data at Vue's componenet in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using Laravel and Vue's component, and when i try to access the banners property from response returned by axios in vue component it gives me undefined.

I am accessing the perperty like `response.data.banners`

**I'm returning data from controller in following way:**

```
public function getBanners(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['
        banners'=> BannerImage::active()->get()
    ]);
}
```

**Here is how i am accessing axios response**

```
<script>
    export default {

        data: function() {
            return  {
                banners: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get("getBanners").then((res)=> {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log(res.data.banners);
                this.banners = res.data.banners;
            });
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Response by axios**

[image]

All is working before accessing the banners property. Is there anything i am not doing correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an linebreak `↩` between `'` and `banners`, which is shown in the console line 2 `"↩ banners":`

**Problem**

```php
public function getBanners(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['    // <-- ↩ line break
        banners'=> BannerImage::active()->get()
    ]);
}
```

**Correct**

```php
public function getBanners(Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        'banners' => BannerImage::active()->get()
    ]);
}
```